# Add sources from other paths don't have CMakeLists.txt, and move output files to other path in CMake

Tags: cmake

My source tree:

```
/project
/project/src/<my sources>
/project/build/vs2008
/project/build/ubuntu
```

I want to put my CMakeLists.txt in `vs2008` and `ubuntu`. I can accept put one CMakeLists.txt to each folder and put another global CMakeLists.txt on `/project/build`, but **I just don't want any CMakeLists.txt in `/project/src`(So I can't use `add_subdirectory` command). I need my solution files of visual studio in `/project/build/vs2008` and Makefile in `/project/build/ubuntu`**. What commands I should know about?

Comment: What is wrong with a CMakeLists.txt in your src/ folder? It is the "idiomatic" way to use CMake. If you don't want your CMakeLists.txt next to your .cpp and .h files, why not add an extra directory around it? E.g. Source/CMakeLists.txt and Source/src/*.

Comment: I think you want an out of source build: http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#What_is_an_.22out-of-source.22_build.3F

Answer (score 1):

I think there's nothing special you would need to know -- you just need to specify paths to your source files relative to where your `CMakeLists.txt` is located, and your targets should build the same as if you had placed `CMakeLists.txt` in your `src` folder. For example, `project/build/ubuntu/CMakeLists.txt` could look like this:

```
set( SrcDir ../../src )
add_executable( MyApp
    ${SrcDir}/file1.cpp
    ${SrcDir}/file2.cpp
    # and so on
)
```

Comment: Yeah, I know that.
At the first thought, there're some command I should set.
Anyway, thanks for the answer.